# PHP: Recursive array function

Tags: php, arrays, oop, recursion

I want to create a function that returns the full path from a set node, back to the root value. I tried to make a recursive function, but ran out of luck totally. What would be an appropriate way to do this? I assume that a recursive function is the only way?

Here's the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Root category
            [_parent] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Category 2
            [_parent] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Category 3
            [_parent] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Category 4
            [_parent] => 3
        )
)
```

The result I want my function to output when getting full path of node id#4:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Root category
            [_parent] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Category 3
            [_parent] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Category 4
            [_parent] => 3
        )
)
```

The notoriously bad example of my recursive skills:

```
    function recursive ($id, $array) {

        $innerarray = array();
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

            if ($v['id'] === $id) {
                if ($v['_parent'] !== '') {
                    $innerarray[] = $v;
                    recursive($v['id'], $array);
                }
            }

        }
        return $innerarray; 
    }
```

Comment: Why not post your code so we can have a look? Maybe you were closer than you thought.

Comment: There's no need to use recursion. Add your 'foreach' search to my below code to search for the parent ID. If you must use recursion, the problem with your code is you're not keeping the return value of the recursive function, you need to append it to your $innerarray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming "id" in your sub array is that sub arrays index + 1 inside the parent array (otherwise you would need to do a search in the array each time), you could do this:

```
$searchNode = 4;
while ($searchNode)
{
    $result[] = $nodes[$searchNode - 1];
    $searchNode = $nodes[$searchNode - 1]["id"];
}
$result = array_reverse($result);
```

Comment: Note that this does not check for loops or other 'errors' in the indexes.